# How to move files to folders in github?

Tags: git, github

I had a bunch of files in a folder and i pushed the whole folder to a github repo.

Then, I said to myself, "I should have these files in seperate subfolders"...So, I made some subdirectories, committed the changes and pushed again.

Now, my remote repo has the subdirectories with all the files I separated, but it also has all the files in the top level directory in the repo!

How do I sync github to my local repo copy?

Comment: git rm the files in the top level, git add the new directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are, you  moved the files into the new directories, added the files at their destination, but you did not tell Git to remove the originals.

You can do so by typing `git rm <file>` for each of the files in the root directory which you'd like removed, or by typing `git add -u` will stage all of the changes (including deletions) and committing the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git mv` command instead of regular `mv` to avoid this in future. `git mv` will stage the moved files appropriately so that they can be committed in a way that they do not create duplicates.